# Incredibly slow transfer rates to/from vm

Tags: virtual-machines, linux-networking, software-raid

Recently I set up a software raid on Ubuntu (which is on an SSD) using Webmin which worked fine and is also fast. I left some space on the SSD on which I installed a Windows 8.1 Pro vm using virt-manager. In virt-manager I created a raw disk image on the raid disk and added it to the Windows vm. So far so good, file transfer speeds from the vm boot drive (the SSD) to the raid disk and vice-versa are totally fine. BUT if I transfer a file over gigabit ethernet from a different pc via the Windows vm onto the raid disk, I only get a fifth of the speed (roughly 30MB/s)! How can that be? Thanks in advance for your answers.

**Additional information:**

- SSD: Ubuntu (Host) and Windows vm
- RAID: Software raid in Ubuntu using Webmin (fast and stable); two drives in raid 0 (for testing only) getting about 150MB/s write/read
- VM: Raw, fixed size disk image on raid disk included with virt-manager
- Ethernet: Gigabit for both the host and the vm (same slow speeds using NAT/virtual bridge)
- Other PC: Directly connected with gigabit ethernet over gigabit ethernet switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some additional researches I finally found the explanation! It seems like the network interface I used for the vm (the standard one provided by Ubuntu and maybe many more) **named rtl....** is extremely slow but works out of the box. The one I use now (and you should use probably too) is the one **named VirtIO**. 
 But first you need to install drivers that you can download here: 
 https://docs.fedoraproject.org/quick-docs/en-US/creating-windows-virtual-machines-using-virtio-drivers.html

 Because my vm is running Windows I downloaded "Stable virtio-win iso" (from above page) under "Direct downloads" while using the **rtl....** interface. I then changed the network interface to **VirtIO** and restarted the vm. Mounted the iso as DVD drive and installed the drivers manually with the device manager. 
 And that's it! Hope this helps someone else out ;)